# How to check if VSTest-Engine only runs one single Test (C# Unittesting)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, vstest

we need to determinate, if a **single** unit test or a **whole solution/project** is called in visual studio per rightclick -> "Run Unit Tests" (per Resharper).

We need this to execute different preperations.
We already tried to differ in "TestContext.TestName", the Process-Start Parameters and even looked in the callstack but we found no-where an useful information.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: vstest or resharper? they're kind of different runners :)

Comment: It could be MSTest, VSTest and Resharper... we solved the problem by writing a completly new "unit-Test-Like" Framework, its not exactly the same like mstest/vsteset but it fits or requirements much better.

Comment: Just remember that somebody will have to maintain that. All of the external frameworks, bugs and limitations of those are battle tested by thousands of people on the globe. Whatever you write yourself will be used by a couple of hundred developers in your company, at best.